# how do i get the ip addresses and names of vm in avariable

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to retrieve a list of all the vms which have the name "*server*" in them and also the ip addresses of these machines. The below works great for getting the names, however how can i add the private ip address of each vm into the variable?

```
$machines = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup | where {$_.Name -like server" + "*"}
```

Comment: `$_.Name -like '*server*'` is the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

`Get-AzureRmVM` Cmdlet doesn't get the IP Address info of any VM.

You have to get the NetworkInterface Name from the `Get-AzureRmVM` and then pass the value to `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface` Cmdlet to get the Private IP .

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName TestRG | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*server*'} | ForEach-Object {
    $NIC = $_.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.id -replace '^.*/'
    $RGName = $_.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.id -replace '^.*resourceGroups/(.*)/providers.*','$1'    
    $IP = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NIC -ResourceGroupName $RGName).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
    [PSCustomObject]@{VMName = $_.Name ; PrivateIpAddress = $IP}
}
```

Or You can directly call the `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface` and filter VM with the VirtualMachine.ID property

```
$Resourcegroup = 'TestRG'; $VmName = 'server'
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.VirtualMachine.ID -match "^.*resourceGroups/$Resourcegroup.*virtualMachines/.*$VmName.*" } | 
    Select-Object @{L='VMName';ex = {$_.VirtualMachine.Id -replace '^.*/'}}, @{L='PrivateIpAddress';ex = {$_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress}}
```

Comment: I ran the command above and allocated a variable to it eg $machines 
It gives the following output.                                                       
VMNAme   PrivateIpAddress
Server1  10.0.0.4
Server2  10.0.0.5

How can i refer to the ip address in the  $machines variable. I tried $machines.PrivateIpAddress but it doesnt work. I need to loop around for each machine name and ip and pass the parameters for vmname and ip address to an ARM Template parameter,

Comment: i am able to access $machines.PrivateIpAddress... $machines | foreach {cmd -param $_.VMName -param $_.PrivateIpAddress}