# Retrieve private IP of azure Linux machine using power-shell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

How can I retrieve private IP address of an Azure Linux VM through power-shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i get the ip addresses and names of vm in avariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270873/how-do-i-get-the-ip-addresses-and-names-of-vm-in-avariable)

Comment: Try the command `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name nicName -ResourceGroupName groupName | Select-Object { $_.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this script

`Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name [Your Nic] -ResourceGroupName [Your RG]`

You will get all the information for Ip addresses needed.

Comment: OK,  I got it. By using the command below we can retrieve private IP address and store it into a variable,                                                                                            
" $IP = (Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $RGName).IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress"